# Adding additional table rows using Angular after using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

New to angular, still working out the many kinks that I hit. I've got a question to pose to you all.

I currently have a table that is being populated on load with ng-repeat. The data itself is a bunch of sums of money. One particular entry, is a collection of those sums. I have an ng-onclick on it to run my function getLadders() when clicked. I would like it to basically pan out below wherever that element is in the chart, and create new rows of the data that is in that particular element.

A mini - drawing of the data it, as I can not paste the exact data.

```
ID        Name         Total

1         Single        $20
2         Single        $35
3         Combination   $60***
4         Single        $10
```

That is the current chart, with combination being the data with the many breakdowns within it. On click of that row, I want it to do something like this.

```
ID        Name         Total

1         Single        $20
2         Single        $35
3         Combination   $60***
3.1       Single        $20
3.2       Single        $20
3.3       Single        $20
4         Single        $10
```

Basically, break out into everything inside that one piece. I have the function written with the extracted data, I have, right now, plain old jQuery to select that row, and append a tablerow after it, but it ends up attaching it to the end of the whole table instead of at that line.

Any help?

Also, for added benefits, I also have an icon on that row that I am looking to alter as well. It's a plus sign, that I want to be a minus sign when the data is being shown, and then back to a plus sign afterwards.

```
    <tbody ng-controller="myCDsController">
    <tr ng-repeat="holding in holdings" ng-if="holding.type !== 'Ladder'" data-type="{{holding.typeClass}}" data-id="{{holding.id}}">
        <td>{{holding.type}}</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">{{holding.name}}</td>
        <td>{{holding.maturityDate}}</td>
        <td>{{holding.amount | currency:"$"}}</td>
        <td>{{holding.rate | percentage:2}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="holding in holdings" ng-if="holding.type == 'Ladder'" ng-controller="openLaddersController"  data-type="{{holding.typeClass}}" data-id="{{holding.id}}">
        <td><i ng-class="{'icon-dislike': !icon,  'icon-plus':icon}" ng-click="openLadders(holding.id)" >dfgh</i> {{holding.type}}</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">{{holding.name}}</td>
        <td>{{holding.maturityDate}}</td>
        <td>{{holding.amount | currency:"$"}}</td>
        <td>{{holding.rate | percentage:2}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code for the table piece? For the icon, you can do something like this: <i class="icon" ng-click="collapsed = !collapsed" ng-class="{ 'icon-plus': !collapsed, 'icon-minus': collapsed }"></i>

Comment: Hi @Daniel Just added the table. I had a question about that, I have the ng-click starting a function, can I still do that?

Comment: Sure, you could add a semicolon and just put my code after, but probably better to include my line in the function call, but it would be $scope.collapsed = !$scope.collapsed. Are you able to provide a jsfiddle with an example? Using jquery to do the child updates is likely the wrong decision in an angular world.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. there are way too many functions that get called to make the data. I think I would be able to understand the concepts though. I'll attempt to make one with random data.

Comment: @Daniel The icon works great, so that's one thing out of the way.

Comment: I tried to hint at concepts in my answer below, it's untested, but at least should be a starting ground for questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some guidance based on what you have above. You should probably simplify the table structure into something like this:

```
<tbody ng-controller="myCDsController">
    <tr ng-repeat="holding in holdings" data-type="{{holding.typeClass}}" data-id="{{holding.id}}">
        <td><i ng-if="holding.type === 'Ladder'" ng-class="{'icon-dislike': !icon,  'icon-plus':icon}" ng-click="openLadders(holding)" >dfgh</i>{{holding.type}}</td>
        <td contenteditable="true">{{holding.name}}</td>
        <td>{{holding.maturityDate}}</td>
        <td>{{holding.amount | currency:"$"}}</td>
        <td>{{holding.rate | percentage:2}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="!icon" ng-if="holding.type === 'Ladder'>
        <td colspan="5">
            <table>
               <tbody>
                   <tr ng-repeat="child in holding.children">
                       <td><!-- insert child content here --></td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

There is probably a better way to handle the data-id / data-type attributes above, but I need more context.

Also, notice that I removed one of your controllers; I somehow doubt you need two controllers for this use case. Your controller should look something like this, probably:

```
app.controller('myCDsController', function(holding) {
   $scope.openLadders = function() {
       holding.children = getChildRows(holding)   
   }
})
```